# jQuery Cut input field misses text

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, swap

I got a problem with form elements I want to move. This is my simple sample. There are two links to move the  containers up or down.

```
<div class="unique_a unique_a_1" data-attr="unique_a_1">
  <a href="move('unique_a', 'up', 1)">Up</a>
  <a href="move('unique_a', 'down', 1)">Down</a>
  <input value="aaa">
</div>

<div class="unique_b unique_b_2" data-attr="unique_b_2">
  <a href="move('unique_b', 'up', 2)">Up</a>
  <a href="move('unique_b', 'down', 2)">Down</a>
  <input value="bbb">
</div>
```

The problem happens, when I click one of the fields, change the value of the input field and try to change my

```
function move( div, direction, counter )
{
  if( direction == 'up' ) {
    var field = $("."+ div +"_"+ counter).prev().attr("data-attr");
  } else {
    var field = $("."+ div +"_"+ counter).next().attr("data-attr");
  }

  if( field != undefined )
  {
    // Clicked element
    var current = $("."+ div +"_"+ counter).html();

    // <div> to change position with
    var other = $("."+ field).html();

    // Empty destination <div> and put in code of clicked element
    $("."+ field).empty().prepend(current);

    // Empty clicked element
    $("."+ div +"_"+ counter).empty().append(other);
  }
```

I got the problem, that if I write "ggg" to the first input field and move it down, it loses "ggg" and shows "aaa".

How can I put text to the fields and then sort the elements and keep the text I wrote?

Comment: Why not just move the elements around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the elements around!

Also - you are shooting yourself in the foot with all those unique identifiers, and keeping track of them.  You don't need any for this.  When a click event, for example, occurs - the browser tells you which thing was clicked on in the handler by setting the value of `this`.  I exploit that to get the div that we want to move around.

Assigning the handler once (as a delegated handler) allows you to add more and more ".movable"s dynamically without having to worry about assigning a handler to each one individually.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".movable .move-up", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get the div that surrounds the button that was clicked
  var thisDiv = $(this).closest(".movable");
  // see if there is a previous div, if so move thisDiv to before it.
  var p = thisDiv.prev('.movable');
  if (p.length > 0) {
    p.before(thisDiv);
  }
});

$("body").on("click", ".movable .move-down", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var thisDiv = $(this).closest(".movable");
  var n = thisDiv.next('.movable');
  if (n.length > 0) {
    n.after(thisDiv);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='movable'>
  <button class='move-up'>Up</button>
  <button class='move-down'>Down</button>
  <input value="aaa">
</div>

<div class='movable'>
  <button class='move-up'>Up</button>
  <button class='move-down'>Down</button>
  <input value="bbb">
</div>

<div class='movable'>
  <button class='move-up'>Up</button>
  <button class='move-down'>Down</button>
  <input value="ccc">
</div>

<div class='movable'>
  <button class='move-up'>Up</button>
  <button class='move-down'>Down</button>
  <input value="ddd">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are hardcoding the values of the inputs.  Try to save the values before you get the html and assign it back after you append/prepend

Comment: It is the same if I leave them blank and put in some content. I can't save the content before putting them into the right position and submitting the form.

Comment: I mean create a variable in your move function that saves the current value of the input, and then assign it back after you put them in their right position

Comment: This is just a very simple example.  There can be more and individual input fields in each <div>. I would like to be able to write in each field and simply change its position.

Comment: var currentVal = current.find('input').val();

Comment: and then after you swap them: $("."+ field).find('input').val(currentVal);